# Upsizing Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I use Access 2010 and SQL Server 2005.  I am new to the process of "upsizing" which I understand is a legacy term.  When I make changes to published tables, I like to localize them back into Access, alter them with the Access interface, and then "re-upsize" them to SQL Server.  When I "re-uspize" an altered table Access warns me:

> "A table named xxxx already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?"

I choose yes.  Then Access reports an error

> "Server Error 3726: Could not drop object 'xxxx' because it is
>   referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint."

I understand the importance of foreign key constraints. I have encountered this same trouble using MySQL.  In MySQL I would simply `set Foreign_Key_Checks = 0;`  before the import, then `set Foreign_Key_Checks = 1;` when finished.

Unfortunately in SQL Server, a table cannot be dropped while it's keys are *only* disabled, they must be deleted.  I don't want to delete and recreate foreign keys every time I alter a table.  Do I need to start altering my tables in the SQL Server environment? Is there a way to easily "Re-upsize" a table and ignore foreign Key constraints?

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you keep moving back and forth between Access and SQL?  Can you make the changes is a test environment in SQL before publishing them to production?  This seems like it would avoid a lot of unnecessary hassle.

Comment: Perhaps I need you to clarify.  I feel I am using Access as a development environment, then pushing the changes to SQL Server, my live environment.

Comment: Ah - Typically when I have worked with folks doing SQL development and done it myself I either have a local copy of the database or work against a dev environment and do most of the development through SQL Management Studio.

Comment: So, you suggest altering my tables in the SQL Server Environment, and using access exclusively for font end?

Comment: That "re-uspize" idea is the worst I have ever seen. Forget about that !

Comment: Just drop the entire sql database, seeing as you are prepared to drop tables. Saying that you'd need a gun to make me work this way. Why not just use another instance of sql server for dev work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use Access for a front end, instead of keeping an Access DB locally and dealing with the issues of moving back and forth. Try to use Access and connect directly to a version of the sql database you can develop against directly through access.  You will probably want to look into using a linked datasource in Access to SQL.

[Connecting SQL Server to an Access Database](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/74858.aspx)